# How to run php script in png/jpg extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, security, web

How can i edit .htaccess file to make client run php script, but in png/jpg extension. Soo...
User will visit url

http://example.com/script.png and he will see "test"(php script will return this value), not image.
That's what i already did:
.htaccess file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .png
```

script.png file:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
echo 'test';
?>
```

What is wrong with this code? Why it doesn't work? Browser tries to download the image :/

Comment: i have tried also making other extensions - browser still wanted to download file

Comment: I never come up with this type of thing. is it possible? i am keen to know.

Comment: If you use the `header()` method, then it won't return 'test', but will read it as an image.

Comment: I have deleted he header() and still doesn't work

Comment: Try to set content type to "text/plain"

Comment: Is this question being asked with white hat intent?

Comment: @yentsun when i set content type to text/plain it shows just text(with the php headers), not executing php code

Comment: @Anantkumarsingh Yes it is possible, we just need to tell the server to make it possible for us.

Comment: @McGrasus than the `AddType` directive is not working properly. You should make Apache (or whatever http-server you are using) recognize `.png` as php first. Than the `text/plain` content-type header should output plain text instead of image.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following line to your `.htaccess` file

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .png
```

This tells the server to process all files ending with `.png`   as `.php`.

Comment: seems to doesnt work for me, browser tries to show image

Comment: what do you mean? "image on the directory"? @Starkeen

Comment: I think the problem is with your script.png file, as other users have already suggested in their comments you are using wrong Content type, change the content type to text/html , or remove this, You have already told your server to read png as php

Comment: If the directory / virtual host is set to `AllowOverride None`, the settings in `.htaccess` will not be working.

Comment: @Raptor That's true!!